# vim wildmode=longest,list doesn't work when files are on different directories

Tags: vim

Vim file name autocompletion doesn't work if files are on different directory levels. Steps to reproduce:

1. `set wildmode=longest,list` in vimrc
2. `vim usa1.txt test/usa2.txt`
3. type `:b u` in EX mode, then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, it is expected to auto complete the word up to `:b usa`, which is the common header of two file names. But it just doesn't work.

Any solutions? Thanks a lot!

PS: if the above two files are placed on the SAME directory, it works!!!

Comment: Might be better suited to superuser.com

Comment: Thanks. Just copied and pasted to superuser.com.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to work. Tab completion is for paths rather than filenames, and the paths do not begin with a common string.

Comment: Vim questions belong on SO not SU.  Search meta for a vote on the issue.

Comment: Any ideas on making tab autocompletion on files names work???? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Completion isn't "deep" (that could potentially cost a lot of time, or result in a lot of matches), it only considers the current directory level.